# retrieve the current user id in a session of a user using _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to write hql query to retrieve the current session of a user using this approach

```
@Autowired
    private SessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private Session getSession() {
        return _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
```

I am trying to achieve something like this

```
return getSession().createQuery("SELECT  FROM Users u WHERE u.id = :userIdFromSession AND u.isAdmin = true").list();
```

this is my approach

```
return getSession().createQuery("SELECT  FROM Users u WHERE u.id = " +:getSession() +"AND u.isAdmin = true").list();
```

assuming the getters and setters are in place this is the user entity class

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long timestamp;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "adminId",nullable = false)
    Admin admin;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private boolean isAdmin;
```

assuming getters and setters, this is the chat entity class

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "chatId")
    private Long id;
    private String message;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    User user;
```

now you can see that chat references user. you must be a user before you can chat, so I want to retrieve the chat of a user this way in dao class

```
// return getSession().createQuery("SELECT  FROM Chats u WHERE u.id = :userIdFromSession AND u.isAdmin = true").list();
```

this is the method I am using to create a user in my controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create-user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView createUser(HttpServletRequest request,
                                   HttpServletResponse response,
                                   @RequestParam String name,
                                   @RequestParam String email) {
        try {
            // create new user object
            User user = new User();
            user.setName(name);
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setTimestamp(new Date().getTime());

            // save user in db (if new)
            if (_userDao.getByEmail(email) == null) {
                _userDao.save(user);
            }

            // save in cookie
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie("name", name);
            Cookie cookie1 = new Cookie("email", email);
            response.addCookie(cookie);
            response.addCookie(cookie1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            //logger.error("Exception in creating user: ", e.getStackTrace());
        }

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
    }
```

this approach is not just working out as it throwing compilation error.
Kindly assist!

Comment: So you vaguely replaced ``":userIdFromSession"`` with ``:getSession()`` (which isnt even valid java) and stop trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Hibernate Session](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) has nothing to do with the user's session. You can think of it in terms of connection to the database.

`SessionFactory#getCurrentSession()` returns the current session if one is already open. Through it, you can query the database.

The way I understand your problem now, is to identify the Spring MVC controllers that will deal with authentication. Your createUser() method may be one of them, but surely you will also need an authenticateUser() somewhere. Let's pretend email are unique and you use the email as a login to authenticate users. Let's suppose that your getByEmail method returns a User POJO. I'll leave exception handling and Spring MVC stuff out.

```
public ModelAndView authenficateUser(HttpServletRequest request,
                               HttpServletResponse response,
                               @RequestParam String email) {
    User u = _userDao.getByEmail(email);
    if (u == null) {
        // deal with unknown user and return to login form
    } else {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("email", email);
        // success
    }
}
```

Then you should have a getChats method in a controller somewhere.

```
public ModelAndView getChats(HttpServletRequest request,
                               HttpServletResponse response) {
    String email = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("email");        
    if (email == null) {
        // user is not logged in, deal with it.
    } else {
        List<Chat> chats = _chatDao.getChats(email);
        return new ModelAndView("chatView", "chats", chats);
    }
}
```

In ChatDao, you have a method like this:

```
List<Chat> getChats(String email) {
    String hql = "from Chat c where c.user.email = :email";
    _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql).setParameter("email", email).list();
}
```

Comment: @f1sh, true enough, but there's no pure Hibernate solution to his problem.

Comment: okay, so how do I construct the right query with this considering my approach above. Please be more specific to the problem, now you have a better idea

Comment: As I wrote, there is no Hibernate solution to your problem. No query can help you there as Hibernate is but a library to deal with ORM. You need a mean to match the user's session (I mean Web Session or client session here) with the ID you store in the database. Without you telling us first what data you have about the user, through the authentication system and the data structure you have in the database, and what type of application and what framework if any... it's quite impossible to help

Comment: So are you suggesting I should add the user entity fields

Comment: Do you have authentication? Are all your users authenticated? If the answer is yes, and your application is a Web application, then you could store the login in the HttpSession http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/?javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html, then if your USERS table doesn't have the login field, I suggest you add it. Then you pass the login from the HttpSession to the database tier and make it a parameter of your query.

Comment: yes I do, i am storing them using cookie and httpsession. I have editted my question with code description to what I am aiming at

Comment: I understand you intend to use the name field to retrieve your user, fine by me if you can guarantee uniqueness of this data. Personally, I would add the `name` to the HttpSession like this: `request.getSession().setAttribute("name", name);` then use it when calling your DAO / repository method.

Comment: i should add additional field called username to my class and wire it to the database

Comment: the dao method you mean is it the one i will use to retrieve the :userIdFromSession

Comment: Yes and not necessarily. If the name is merely for display, you can do what you please. But, the field you will use to recognize a user must be unique, i.e. the login / username must be.

Comment: please now you have a better understanding can you post a snippet. thanks